# How to set the fixed column width values in inches. Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, column-width

Im setting fixed widths for the columns for the excel im creating with Apache POI. Im having the fixed values in inches. So I want to know what is the measurement that Apcahe POI is taking as a parameter. And how can I call it using the values in inches?

`Sheet sheet;
 sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 100);`

Answer (score 2):

In [Sheet.setColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-) is told that the measurement unit here is 1/256th of a character width. It also is told how exactly `Excel` calculates this.

So if one wants `Excel` shall show column width as 10, using default font Calibri 11, then the `width256` must be calculated as `(int)Math.round((10*Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH+5f)/Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH*256f)`.

If the need is setting the column width in inches, then first the inches should be translated to pixels and then the `width256` must be calculated as `(int)Math.round(widthPx/Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH*256f)`.

There is [Units](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html) as a helper class for unit management.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

class ExcelSetColumnWidth {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   int widthExcel = 10;
   int width256 = (int)Math.round((widthExcel*Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH+5f)/Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH*256f);
   System.out.println(width256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, width256);
   sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("1234567890"); // Excel shows column width as 10 using default font Calibri 11

   float widthInch = 1f;
   float widthPx = widthInch * Units.PIXEL_DPI;
   width256 = (int)Math.round(widthPx/Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH*256f);
   System.out.println(width256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(1, width256);
   System.out.println(sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(1)); // should be round 96 pixels for an inch
   sheet.createRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue("1 inch width"); // column is 1 inch width

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I cant seem to resolve `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH` from the Units helper class

Comment: @dinesh alwis: What `apache poi` version are you using? See here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/constant-values.html#org.apache.poi.util.Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH.