# Can not accurately set Excel column width Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is my code (Java)

```java
sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 100 * 256);
```

I expect the width of column 1 of the generated excel to be `100`. But the actual width in excel is `99.22` . The search engine did not provide a reasonable explanation, can anyone help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021996/how-to-set-the-fixed-column-width-values-in-inches-apache-poi/58022866#58022866.

Comment: @AxelRichter  I have a try , But did not get the expected result, thank you still

Comment: Works for me using default Excel and default font Calibri 11. If I set `int widthExcel = 100;`, I get first column exactly in width 100. What have you tried? What result do you get? What apache poi version? What Excel version? What default font used?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel the column width 100 means that 100 default characters in default font and default font size fit into the cell. So how width 100 exactly is varies with default font and default font size. The default font and default font size is given by cell style Normal given in Styles group in Home tab.

In storage Excel stores the width having additional padding. So coulmn widt 100 is not exactly stored as 100 but as 100 + padding. But also the padding differs for different default fonts and default font sizes used.

Apache POI using `XSSF` (Office Open XML format) takes font Calibri and font size 11 as the defaults. Those are the defaults used by Excel too. So `Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH` of Apache POI is default character width of that default font in size 11.

So using following column width setting:

```
...
   int widthExcel = 100;
   int width256 = (int)Math.round((widthExcel*Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH+5f)/Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH*256f);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, width256);
...
```

should set column width exactly 100 in Excel if that Excel uses font Calibri and font size 11 as the defaults in cell style Normal.

Using other defaults the `Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH` in the calculation must be replaced by other default character widths.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code(I got it from here https://blog.csdn.net/ab411919134/article/details/17606399):

```
sheet.setColumnWidth(0, (int) ((100 + 0.73) * 256));
```

The post mentioned that it should be 0.72, but 0.73 is correct for me

This excel column width meets expectations, but I still don’t know why